# { "error": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "authentication failure" }

Tags: rest-api, authentication

i am accessing my developer instance to create a connected app in sfdc. Firstly i could not find Reset security token link in my sandbox instance. However, i followed the blogs to generate link to get the token.

With this i was able to generate security token. But unfortunately, after performing a post request, i am getting the below response in my rest client.

[image: Connected app details]
[image: parameters in Rest client]

Comment: Please, never share client secrets - tokens - passwords (sensitive data) in your posts. Additional, refrain from asking for help and yous subject should be a brief representative description of your post, not a copy paste of an Error. take some time to visit [ask] and take the [tour] in order to get familair with the forum. thanks

Comment: You say in your post that you're logging in to your sandbox, but the URL is `login.salesforce.com`. Are you sure you're targeting the right environment?

Comment: have editted my post. Its developer instance.